# What is annotation processing in Java?

Tags: java, annotations, javac

Quoting, [Sun's Official Java Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/getStarted/problems/index.html)

> Class names, 'HelloWorldApp', are only
>   accepted if annotation processing is
>   explicitly requested

What does it mean? And how to apply it?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/problems/index.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

"Annotation Processing" is a hook into the compile process of the java compiler, to analyse the source code for user defined annotations and handle then (by producing compiler errors, compiler warning, emitting source code, byte code ...).

API reference: [javax.annotation.processing (Java Platform SE 6)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 10):

From the very next line of the [page](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/getStarted/problems/index.html) that you refer to:

> **Class names, 'HelloWorldApp', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested**
>
> If you receive this error, you forgot to include the .java suffix when compiling the program. Remember, the command is javac HelloWorldApp.java not javac HelloWorldApp.

That is, the string that you are referring to is a possible error that you might get when trying to compile the examples. The *very next* line in the document, tells you how to resolve the issue.

If you want to know more about annotations, what they are, and how to use them, then I would suggest to go through the [Annotations tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/).

Comment: Question: "What is annotation processing in Java?"

Comment: @Earwicker: That is the title of the question, now read the text of the question: this page says blah, what does that mean?

Comment: Yeah, I read it. It doesn't say the OP has hit *any* kind of compile error they can't fix. It says (again) they want to know what annotation processing is.

Comment: @Earwicker: I have updated my answer to answer both interpretations of the question.

Comment: Link to 'Annotations tutorial' is not valid

Answer (score 2):

This error is due to incorrect use of java compilation command i.e javac with file name w/o java extension (.java)

Use proper compilation command

> javac HelloWorldApp.java

Command used foe execution

> java HelloWorldApp